# How to save a rotated canvas element to a file

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, transform

I am trying to rotate a large image and save it as a file. I've tried several methods that fail due to the large image size. (OpenCV, Paint Shop Pro, etc).

So, I am trying to do this with javascript. I can draw the image onto a rotated canvas (this works), but when I try to save the canvas to a file, the rotation is lost. It makes sense that this happens, but would like to understand how to capture/extract the rotated state of the canvas before saving?

The client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function initPage() {
                var imageObj = new Image();
                imageObj.onload = function() {
                    // Draw onto rotated canvas
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('mapCanvas');
                    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

                    // Save image as png
                    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "savePNG.php?file=FN617_ROT",
                      data: { 
                         imgBase64: dt
                      }
                    }).done(function(o) {
                      console.log('saved'); 
                    });

                };  
                imageObj.src = 'FN617.png';
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #mapCanvas {
                transform-origin:center center;
                transform: rotate(-32.5deg);
            }
        </style>       
    </head>

    <body onload="initPage();">
        <canvas id="mapCanvas" width="9600" height="7200"></canvas>
    </body> 
</html>
```

The server code:

```
<?php
    $base64 = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $_REQUEST['imgBase64']);
    $data = base64_decode($base64);
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/". $_GET['file'].".png", $data);
?>
```

Comment: If this is a 1-off project, you can sign up for a 30-day trial of Photoshop to easily achieive your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you capture canvas you are capturing the bitmap, not the element. CSS only affects element - as with a plain image, rotating it doesn't actually change the original image in any way.

In order to properly do this, first remove the CSS rotation.

Then apply rotation using the transformation methods of the context. Note here that CSS by default rotates around the center. This is not the case with canvas which rotates by the top left corner, so we need to translate first.

Here are the steps:

```
// translate to center where the rotation will take place:
context.translate(context.canvas.width * 0.5, context.canvas.height * 0.5);

// rotate (uses radians)
context.rotate = -32.5 * 180 / Math.PI;

// translate back as image is drawn from (0,0)
context.translate(-context.canvas.width * 0.5, -context.canvas.height * 0.5);

// draw image
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
```

Optionally, if image does not correspond with the size of canvas, do the backward translation using the image's size instead.

```
context.translate(context.canvas.width * 0.5, context.canvas.height * 0.5);
context.rotate = -32.5 * 180 / Math.PI;
context.drawImage(imageObj, -imageObj.width * 0.5, -imageObj.height * 0.5);
```

Now you can capture canvas with a rotated image.

Note that a canvas of this size may not work in all browsers, and if it does it may not allow you to capture a data-uri of it as some browsers has size limits to those. Just something to have in mind..

Comment: "Now you can capture canvas with a rotated image." - any chance you could expand on that.  How do you 'extract' a canvas image and send it off to a back-end for saving?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `localStorage`, but not with a file for security reasons.

Comment: Local Storage won't help. It is a storage mechanism, not an image transformation tool. Also, svenyonson says the file is extra large and localStorage has a rather small file size limit--I believe 10mb or so.